# Eclipse with JDK 7 ending up with Errors

Tags: eclipse, jdk

Ive tried to set up Eclipse with suns jdk 7 and end aup with some errors on 12.4 I'm not shure how to fix this issue, because I'm a novice to ubuntu

any Ideas?

> -- Error Messages --
>
> !SESSION 2012-06-10 13:27:12.607 -----------------------------------------------
>   eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
>   java.version=1.7.0_04
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
>   Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-06-10 13:27:18.326
>   !MESSAGE Anwendungsfehler
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
>     no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
>     no swt-gtk in java.library.path
>     Can't load library: /home/joachim/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
>     Can't load library: /home/joachim/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so>
>
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.(C.java:21)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Display.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
>     at >org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java>:153)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

Comment: With some Google-fu I find the right soulution by myself 

Google helps sp much!

There is just an issue with the patch of the gtk so library file.

The easiest way to fix it is

ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/

is the reason to fix the path for the gtk.so file 

you could do it for 32bit systems by change the last bit of the path